# Why QtWebkit 4.8.0 ( Webkit 2.2 ) dont support Audio & Video?

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

If I install Qt 4.7.4 with QtWebKit 2.0.2 (built for Visual Studio 2008) I immediately run one of the delivered examples (e.g. the Fancy Browser) which uses the QtWebKit. Then I browse to http://www.html5test.com [html5test.com] and I get (among others) these results

20/31 video points
20/20 audio points
19/20 web application points

Okay, cool so far.

I did the very same with Qt 4.8 RC1 and the included QtWebKit 2.2 (built for Visual Studio 2010), I get these results:

0/31 video points
0/20 audio points
15/20 web application points (the 4 points less are caused by missing support for ‘Custom content handlers’)

So, no audio and video support with the new version?!

http://ng1.upanh.com/b6.s15.d1/168f4bd62b3688b159282bf731713b02_39426931.2.png
http://ng9.upanh.com/b5.s13.d4/bdce7d70277d7b25c44ef84ea96b4c30_39427079.thehtml5testhowwelldoesyourbrows.png

Comment: It definitely supports audio and video. You need to use gstreamer for that.  http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/webkit-qt/2011-June/001633.html

Answer (score 3):

According to folks on the QtWebkit mailing list, the problem is that Trolltech moved the multimedia support into QtMobility, and dropped the Phonon support that the previous QtWebkit used.  Unfortunately they do not include the new QtMultimediaKit with Qt 4.8, and so the QtWebkit cannot depend on it.

So there is no multimedia available in Qt4.8/QtWebkit2.2 without:
Getting QtMultimediaKit from QtMobility and building it against Qt 4.8 ( http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/installation.html, I had only minor issues building it)
Getting QtWebkit 2.2 from webkit.org ( http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKitRelease22#SourceCodeandBuildInstructions ) and building it with the QtMultmediaKit available to it.  I have not done this yet so I cannot tell you exactly what to do.

Also, note there is a bug open against this, apparently it was a known issue in the 4.8rc but they chose not to address it. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-22883

Comment: +1 Phonon is past. However, it's a shame that QtMultimediaKit is not quite there yet. I've had inumerous problems with QtMultimediaKit playing videos with QML: all sorts of visual defects.

Comment: Yes, it is very odd though because they still distributed Phonon with Qt4.8, but did not distribute QtMediakKit, though QtWebkit 2.2 would have depended on it for media support.  It sounds like they got caught in the middle of a transition.  Possibly caused by the Nokia and Symbian implosion.  And thanks for mentioning the QtMultimediaKit issues, I won't get my hopes up.

Answer (score 0):

Qt 4.8 and latest version 5.0.2 doesn't support video.. here is the link
 http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23636

You can resolve the issue by using this blog. Sorry I did not tried this. may help you. You need to build qt twice and few more corrections!
http://blog.enthought.com/open-source/fun-with-qtwebkit-html5-video/

Some one already mentioned the qt open bug against it.
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-22883